# Symfony3 - Define service outside src/bundle

Tags: symfony, serialization, service, dependency-injection, bundle

I am trying to define service outside src, in App\Service to be exact. I know that service in Symfony is just a class therefore I should be able to put it anywhere.

That's what I've got at the moment:

## app\config\services.yml

```
parameters:
  serializer_service_class: App\Service\SerializeService

services:
    app.serializer:
        class: '%serializer_service_class%'
        autowire: true
```

Service is just a simple serializing class:

## SerializeService.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

/**
 * Class SerializeService
 * @package App\Service
 */
class SerializeService
{
/**
 * @var Serializer
 */
private $serializer;

/**
 * @var array
 */
private $encoders;

/**
 * @var array
 */
private $normalizer;

/**
 * SerializeService constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $this->normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

    $this->normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });

    $this->serializer = new Serializer($this->normalizer, $this->encoders);
}

public function serialize2Json($item)
{
    return $this->serializer->serialize($item, 'json');
}
```

}

Then I get this error message:

```
Attempted to load class "SerializeService" from namespace "App\Service".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I've really tried to find solution for this and I have tried different options. If it is somewhere on stackoverflow please point me to this post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the location where you place your file `SerializeService.php` is not registered to autoload.

Comment: @PigBall good call! Thank you very much. I just had to add it to composer autoload - stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pib Ball said your autoloader is probably missing some infos.

I've tried the following setup

```
myProjectRoot/
    app/
        config/
        Resources/
        Service/
            SerializeService.php <- your service file
```

I have used your code, no changes.

I have the same error as you, then I've edited my composer.json as following

```
................
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "App\\": "app/",
    }
},
```

Then executed the command `composer update` and then your service should be loaded.

Hope it may helps you

Comment: Hi I did exactly like you did it right after Pig Ball wrote his comment and it also worked for me.